# how to display the data in json file in an collapse/accordition Panel

Tags: javascript, html, json

how to display the below data in data.json external file  to html COLLAPSE/ACCORDITION PANEL  data into three different accordition as there are 3 types main type species.so i need to display name of species all the data in that name should open a collapse. for example if i click name Hut in should expand accordition to display all the data in that species like hair_colours,description etc.

{

```
"species": [
 {
        "name": "Hutt", 
        "classification": "gastropod", 
        "designation": "sentient", 
        "average_height": "300", 
        "skin_colors": "green, brown, tan", 
        "hair_colors": "n/a", 
        "eye_colors": "yellow, red", 
        "average_lifespan": "1000", 
        "homeworld": "http://swapi.co/api/planets/24/", 
        "language": "Huttese", 
        "people": [
            "http://swapi.co/api/people/16/"
        ], 
        "films": [
            "http://swapi.co/api/films/3/", 
            "http://swapi.co/api/films/1/"
        ], 
        "created": "2014-12-10T17:12:50.410000Z", 
        "edited": "2014-12-20T21:36:42.146000Z", 
        "url": "http://swapi.co/api/species/5/"
    }, 
    
    {
        "name": "Toydarian", 
        "classification": "mammal", 
        "designation": "sentient", 
        "average_height": "120", 
        "skin_colors": "blue, green, grey", 
        "hair_colors": "none", 
        "eye_colors": "yellow", 
        "average_lifespan": "91", 
        "homeworld": "http://swapi.co/api/planets/34/", 
        "language": "Toydarian", 
        "people": [
            "http://swapi.co/api/people/40/"
        ], 
        "films": [
            "http://swapi.co/api/films/5/", 
            "http://swapi.co/api/films/4/"
        ], 
        "created": "2014-12-19T17:48:56.893000Z", 
        "edited": "2014-12-20T21:36:42.165000Z", 
        "url": "http://swapi.co/api/species/13/"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Dug", 
        "classification": "mammal", 
        "designation": "sentient", 
        "average_height": "100", 
        "skin_colors": "brown, purple, grey, red", 
        "hair_colors": "none", 
        "eye_colors": "yellow, blue", 
        "average_lifespan": "unknown", 
        "homeworld": "http://swapi.co/api/planets/35/", 
        "language": "Dugese", 
        "people": [
            "http://swapi.co/api/people/41/"
        ], 
        "films": [
            "http://swapi.co/api/films/4/"
        ], 
        "created": "2014-12-19T17:53:11.214000Z", 
        "edited": "2014-12-20T21:36:42.167000Z", 
        "url": "http://swapi.co/api/species/14/"
    }
    ]
```

}

Comment: Your description of the problem is not constructive. Please edit your question based on this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you already included JQuery. And bootstrap also. If you haven't done so, give referance to both Jquery and Bootstrap so that you can use objects like Accordion.

After that create an empty div to store accordion object.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion"></div>
```

And create a js file and name it anything you want. And put this code inside it.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url: 'data.json',  //Here you will fetch records, give referance to your JSON file
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          var accordionData;
          accordionData = '';

          for(var i = 0; i < data.species.length; i++){
            accordionData += '<div class="panel panel-default">';
            accordionData += '<div class="panel-heading">';
            accordionData += '<h4 class="panel-title">';
            accordionData += '<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse' + i + '">';
            accordionData += data.species[i].name + '</a>';
            accordionData += '</h4>';
            accordionData += '</div>';
            accordionData += '<div id="collapse' + i + '" class="panel-collapse collapse">';
            accordionData += '<div class="panel-body">';
            accordionData += '<ul>';
            accordionData += '<li><strong>Name : </strong>' + data.species[i].name + '</li>';
            accordionData += '<li><strong>Classification : </strong>' + data.species[i].classification + '</li>';
            accordionData += '<li><strong>designation : </strong>' + data.species[i].designation + '</li>';
            accordionData += '<li><strong>average_height : </strong>' + data.species[i].average_height + '</li>';
            accordionData += '<li><strong>skin_colors : </strong>' + data.species[i].skin_colors + '</li>';
            accordionData += '<li><strong>hair_colors : </strong>' + data.species[i].hair_colors + '</li>';
            accordionData += '<li><strong>eye_colors : </strong>' + data.species[i].eye_colors + '</li>';
            accordionData += '<li><strong>average_lifespan : </strong>' + data.species[i].average_lifespan + '</li>';
            accordionData += '<li><strong>homeworld : </strong>' + data.species[i].homeworld + '</li>';
            accordionData += '<li><strong>language : </strong>' + data.species[i].language + '</li>';
            accordionData += '<li><strong>people : </strong><ul>';
            for(var j = 0; j < data.species[i].people.length; j++){
                accordionData += '<li>' + data.species[i].people[j] + '</li>';
            }
            accordionData += '</ul>';
            accordionData += '<li><strong>films : </strong><ul>';
            for(var k = 0; k < data.species[i].films.length; k++){
                accordionData += '<li>' + data.species[i].films[k] + '</li>';
            }
            accordionData += '</ul>';
            accordionData += '<li><strong>created : </strong>' + data.species[i].created + '</li>';
            accordionData += '<li><strong>edited : </strong>' + data.species[i].edited + '</li>';
            accordionData += '<li><strong>url : </strong>' + data.species[i].url + '</li>';
            accordionData += '</ul>';
            accordionData += '</div></div></div>';

          }

          veriler = data.species[0].name;
          $('#accordion').html(accordionData);


      }
  });
});
```

Don't forget to give referance to this new JS file you created.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourNewFile.js"></script>
```

By the way, i know there is a more elegant way of doing this, but this does the trick. I tested, and its working well.

> NOTE : Curly brackets are missing in your JSON file. Put { at the beginning, and } at the end.
>   EDİT
>   Change the lines between 32 - 39

```
for(var j = 0; j < data.species[i].people.length; j++){
    accordionData += '<li><a href="' + data.species[i].people[j] + '">' + data.species[i].people[j] + '</a></li>';
}
accordionData += '</ul>';
accordionData += '<li><strong>films : </strong><ul>';
for(var k = 0; k < data.species[i].films.length; k++){
    accordionData += '<li><a href="' + data.species[i].films[k] + '">' + data.species[i].films[k] + '</a></li>';
}
```

> EDIT No: 2

Change this line

```
accordionData += '<li><strong>homeworld : </strong>' + data.species[i].homeworld + '</li>';
```

to

```
accordionData += '<li><strong>homeworld : </strong><a href="' + data.species[i].homeworld + '">' + data.species[i].homeworld + '</a></li>';
```

and this line

```
accordionData += '<li><strong>url : </strong>' + data.species[i].url + '</li>';
```

to

```
accordionData += '<li><strong>url : </strong><a href="' + data.species[i].url + '">' + data.species[i].url + '</a></li>';
```

Comment: Ruzer,thanks it works 100% ., but when js data is kept internally it works , when kept in external file it does not work.i have also checked filename and links correctly but it does not work when js kept in new file, but this works for me internally thanks a lot

Comment: how to make links work in films like they should be <a href=" "></a>

Comment: I edited my previous post, Look above. Just change the lines between if statements, and voila.

Comment: <a href=''> not working for homeworld and url